# How to Upload apk expansion files in new Developer console

Tags: android, apk

I have a project of 10 Mb and an expansion file of 100MB, In the new Google Play developer console i have uploaded the apk file.

But how to upload the expansion files?

Comment: I have not tested it, but I think I had seen the option to upload expansion file when the upload of my apk was done....but I am not sure

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As per the docs,

Due to a current limitation of the new Google Play Developer Console, you won't be able to add additional expansion files to the very first APK file that you upload for a new application. As a work-around, please upload first a placeholder APK file and then replace it with an APK file containing the additional expansion files you need. All of this can be performed while the application is still in draft state, so there is no impact on your (prospective) users.

It works for me..

Comment: what is placeholder apk file?

Comment: it's a dummy apk. When you first upload your apk you will not have any option for the expansion files. From second apk onwards you will have that option. It looks weird.

Comment: Just so no ones worried when they see this after they uploaded their 'App' instead of a 'Placeholder', you can just reupload the 'App' again and it removes the last upload, giving you the Expansion file upload options as well.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in the new console, this feature is not supported yet. You need to switch back to the old console.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot upload Expansion files as of now. Instead switch back to Old Developer console.

Comment: Yes....Please read this document on "How to test Expansion files"...http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/google/play/expansion-files.html#Testing

Comment: Yes, i have seen that but its not working for me it says "XAPK File vlaidation failed", i have put the obb files manually in the specified folder.